# How to excute a command when SSH session closes?

Tags: linux, ssh

For example, if I close Putty or just lose Internet connection, how to make the server excute a specific command?

Mikael's solution in the comments works perfectly . Thanks for help

Comment: just type the command quickly before the shell exits?

Comment: PAM should be able to handle this. [Example in this stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136548/force-command-to-be-run-on-logout-or-disconnect)

Comment: @MikaelLevoniemi please, write that as an answer.

Comment: As noted in this [Stackexhange example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136548/force-command-to-be-run-on-logout-or-disconnect) PAM can handle login/logout scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because serverfault defaults my answers to comments, i copied over the proper answer from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136548/force-command-to-be-run-on-logout-or-disconnect) :

The best way to do this would be to use pam.

In /etc/pam.d you will have several files, one of them will be called sshd. If you only want to affect ssh, and not other logins (such as a GUI, or real TTY), you want this file.
If you want to affect all logins, you'll want a 'common' file. The name of this other 'common' file varies by distro, but you can track it down by following the include and substack statements in the sshd file until you get to the base file.

Once you've identified the file in /etc/pam.d that you want to use, add a line such as the following to the session section:

```
session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh
```

This will result in calling /etc/pam_session.sh every time someone logs in and logs out (whether gracefully or ungracefully).

Now you just need to create /etc/pam_session.sh. Below is an example you could use to run something every time someone logs out:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then
  something
fi
```

(don't forget to chmod a+x the script)